# DatePicker in same Dialog with multiple EditText

Tags: java, android, android-layout

This is the example what i want to do but i cant.
i need multiple Edit Text with one date picker in my own dialog box means no need to open the another one for datePicker.
by clicking positiveButton i need the text in the edit text widget and the selected date in the date picker in the form of string or whatever.
i have searched alot but there is no solution for my requirement i hope somebody can solve this issue Thanks in advance.

[image: Example DatePicker with EditText]

This is my code the edit text and the date picker have been initialized...

```
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Add Task");
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialoglayout, null);
            final EditText titleText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.dialogTitleText);
            final EditText descriptionText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.dialogDescriptionText);
                final DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
builder.setView(view);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   ///text + date Required
                    }
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
}
            });
            builder.show();
```

Comment: why is this so difficult??

Comment: Done... :P i was just confused...

Answer (score 0):

By adding this code after datepicker initialization and before builder.setView(view); got the selected date....

```
   datePicker.setCalendarViewShown(false);
            final String date ;

            datePicker.init(datePicker.getYear(), datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth(), new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    date = dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year;
                }
            });
```